# Why inline JavaScript is not working in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, inline, show-hide

I'm writing a PHP site and have a blog. I have a comment field (for all the blogs posts) with a textarea and a submit button in a div tag, but I can't seem to get it working in Internet Explorer. It works fine in Google Chrome. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction.

You can also find the code at [My Code in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksdenmark/MrKq6/)

My HTML Template for the PHP look's like this:

```
<div class="blogbubble">
<table border="0" align="right" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top" width="60px"></td>
        <td align="right"><font size="2"></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">   <b><font size="4">Hello</font></b>
            <br /><font size="3">Hello</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="show_hide" id="comnr">
    <hr>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" style="width:300px;margin-left:60px"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button style="float:right">Comment</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <button style="float:right" onclick= 'document.getElementById("comnr").classList.toggle("show_hide")&document.getElementById("comknap").classList.toggle("show_hide")'>Cancel</button>
</div>
<button id="comknap" onclick='document.getElementById("comnr").classList.toggle("show_hide")&document.getElementById("comknap").classList.toggle("show_hide")'>Comment</button>
```

### My CSS:

```
.show_hide { display:none; }

.blogbubble {
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    width: 95%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    overflow: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: what version of Internet Explorer are you using? It might not support `classList.toggle`

Comment: I have tried with version 9

Comment: Inline javascript *is* working. Only [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) is not supported - you should see that in your error console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kolink has the correct answer as to why the problem is occuring, but if you have the option of using JQuery I recommend the following [solution (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/iantsmall/j7zQS/2/) which is more stable for cross browser coding.

The core change is this [JQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and the [JQuery toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/);

```
 $('[id="comnr"][class="show_hide"],#comknap').toggle();
```

I used three features of JQuery selector here.

The first selection feature used is the [multiple-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) which itself is a combination of two [attribute equals selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as requirements:

```
//A selection of elements whose id is "comnr" and whose class is "show_hide"
var selectionByMultipleRequirements= $('[id="comnr"][class="show_hide"]');
```

The second selection feature used is the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
//A selection of elements whose id is "comknap"
var selectionById = $('#comknap');
```

The third selection feature used is the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) which allows us to combine the previous selections into a list of separate criteria sets (selections returned match at least one of the sets of criteria, each set being separated by a comma):

```
//A selection of elements who either have an id of "comnr" and whose class is "show_hide" OR have an id of "comknap"
var selectionByMultipleCriteria = $('[id="comnr"][class="show_hide"],#comknap');
```

Answer (score 1):

`classList` was only added to IE10. Any version before that does not support it. See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) for a shim.